# Reorder XML nodes

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I’ve got some XML that looks something like this:

```xml
<root>
    <item>Banana</item>
    <item>Apple</item>
    <item>Cherry</item>
</root>
```

It’s not the actual data I have, but it’ll serve the purpose here. What I want to do is use Linq to SQL to reorder the XML so that the child nodes are in alphabetical order, eg.

```xml
<root>
    <item>Apple</item>
    <item>Banana</item>
    <item>Cherry</item>
</root>
```

I want to be able to then call `ToString()` on the original XDocument and have it return the second set of XML as shown above. Is there a simple way of doing this? I’ve tried searching, but no such luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
var reordered = new XElement(
                    "root",
                    xdoc.Root.Elements("item")
                             .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
                             .Select(x => new XElement("item", x.Value)));
```

Or the slightly more flexible (albeit only supporting 1 nested level):

```
var reordered = new XElement(
                    xdoc.Root.Name,
                    xdoc.Root.Elements()
                             .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
                             .Select(x => new XElement(x.Name, x.Value)));
```

Comment: @Dylan: you're welcome. The beauty of XLinq is the extensibility of the constructors of the various objects. I suggest reading [Functional Construction LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387019.aspx) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The problem for me was that I was thinking about it from the wrong angle; I was trying to change the existing XML rather than thinking of creating new XML to replace it.